# Defining a jquery function on SignalR

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, signalr, signalr.client

I am trying to do a "Opened" and "Closed" on SignalR. When someone clicks on the task button, it opens a new modal/popup using Jquery. When someone opens, I wanted to display "Opened" and then when it closed, I wanted to display "Closed". I got Open to work, but I can't seem to get closed working. This is my current code:

```
function StartReservationConnection()
{
    var reservationConnection = $.connection.reservationHub

    reservationConnection.client.reservationOpened = function (contractId, username) {
        ToggleReservationStatus(contractId, username, "open");
    }

    reservationConnection.client.reservationClosed = function (contractId)
    {
        ToggleReservationStatus(contractId, null, "close");
    }

    $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
        $(sections).on('click', '.displayReservationDetails', function () {
            var username = $('#currentUserName').val();
            var contractId = $(this).data("contractid");
            reservationConnection.server.reservationOpened(contractId, username);
        });

        // This does not get called
        function reservationHasClosed(contractId) {
            alert("closed: " + contractId);
        }
    });
}
```

I know I could do some kind of hack and make it like "On Modal Close, do this", but the thing is I need the contractId to be passed back and it seemed like a little more work.

Is there a way I can define a function in signalR, like reservationHasClosed and then call it from the Modal like "Modal:onClosed: reservationHasClosed(id)"

If not, does anyone know efficient way of doing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by doing this:

```
var reservationConnection;
function StartReservationConnection()
{
    // Create a new signalR connection
    reservationConnection = $.connection.reservationHub;
    ...
```

and then later on I can just call it like this:

```
function reservationHasClosed(contractId) {
    reservationConnection.server.reservationClosed(contractId);
}
```

I don't like making reservationConnection global like that though, so if anyone know a better way of doing it, please let me know.